# Should we merge tags employee-stock-options and employee-share-plan

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we merge [create synonyms] the tags [employee-stock-options](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employee-stock-options) and [employee-share-plan](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employee-share-plan), or is there enough distinction to keep both. I guess we can create a distinction, but would need more appropriate definitions for both the tags and undertake a re-tagging exercise for the set of questions.

Comment: BTW thanks for starting this discussion - I don't have a strong view but happy to help out with any cleanup. Apart from creating a synonym we can also (with mod powers) explicitly merge one tag into another which silently removes the old one.

Answer (score 3):

When looking at plan that allow employees to purchase share of the company they fall into several groups:

- shares vs options
- publicly owned companies vs private companies

The placement in this grid determines tax implication, put it also determine what happens if a person leave the company, what happens to their shares. Other tags the exit: [retricted-stock](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retricted-stock) , [option-exercise](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/option-exercise) and [options](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/options) allow the question to be properly binned.

I don't think the two tags make it clear to a questioner what tag(s) are appropriate for their question. So I vote to merge them.

Comment: I don't think I agree. Just based on the tags themselves (because employee-share-plan doesn't have a description, and employee-stock-options' description is weak), I'd say they aren't equivalent, and that employee-share-plan is a strict superset of employee-stock-options (and restricted-stock for that matter).

Comment: @blm Could you post an answer and draw up some description for both the tags. We can then evaluate how many questions we can tag distinctly

Answer (score 2):

the above answer (@mhoran_psprep) dices **some** of the distinction, though in addition to the above, I suggest additional consideration:

1. employee-share-plan typically is offered to **all** employees either pre- or after- tax, depending on the plan after meeting certain requirements: typically minimum length of employment . Somewhat similar to health benefits, etc.
2. employee-stock-options are typically **not** offered to all, but to a few as compensation and as reward for superior performance. In addition, employee-stock-options are not to my knowledge, available in a tax deferred plan.

   In summary, the former is the employee's choice, and the latter is the choice of the **employer**; therefore, I believe the separation is important.

Comment: Agreed. The question is more whether someone coming in for the first time can make this distinction and are the questions being tagged rightly or randomly

Answer (score 1):

"Stock options" and "Share plans" typically have very different risk profiles and tax treatments.  Exercising a stock option can be done in a way that does not require the employee to invest their own cash.  Many stock purchase plans allow the employee to spend cash to purchase stock at a discount.  This up-front investment reduces the number of employees for whom the investment is affordable and prudent.

I think there should be two separate tags.  Perhaps we need to review the tags, to make sure that individual questions are tagged appropriately.